# Why does Internet Explorer render my website horribly?

Tags: internet-explorer, layout

My website looks fine in Firefox and Chrome, but for some reason Internet Explorer renders it horribly. I recently changed the encoding of all the pages from 'Windows-1255' to UTF-8 (maybe this has something to do with it?) In my opinion this is probably a CSS problem, but I do not know what it is.

Site URL: http://roshtof.co.il/

Comment: Possibly related but its declrared using an html dtd but tries to use an xhtml namespace, run it through validator.w3.org

Comment: This is kind of a symbolic question for us web developers...

Comment: cdeszaq - IE 9,8,7
@Alex K. - I changed the doctype to XHTML, but that doesn't help.
joshcomley - Problems in IE... Story of my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check out your css, but I ran your site in IE8 with the debugger enabled (press F12 to enable it), it gives a lot of javascript and AJAX errors. I think this is a good point to start off with because if one script fails it can impact all other scripts on the page.